# Update message roles discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I try to do command that you mention someone and that sends their important roles and that's not updating the roles.

the code:

```
const member =
  message.mentions.members.first() ||
  message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if (!member) return message.reply('תתייג משהו')

const memberRoles = member.roles.cache
  .filter((roles) => roles.id == '851427310656552972' || roles.id == '855439580668231703' || roles.id == '754739387295858828' || roles.id == '780692233367060521' || roles.id == '851089257044508682' || roles.id == '754743308852527166' || roles.id == '849632562724995144' || roles.id == '796320719972859955')
  .map((role) => role.toString());

var msg3 = await message.channel.send(

  new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(
    member.user.tag,
    member.user.displayAvatarURL({
      dynamic: true
    })
  )
  .setDescription(`${member}'s roles => ${memberRoles}`)
  .setColor('RANDOM')
)

setInterval(() => {
  msg3.edit(
    new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(
      member.user.tag,
      member.user.displayAvatarURL({
        dynamic: true
      })
    )
    .setDescription(`${member}'s roles => ${memberRoles}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
  )
}, 5000);
}
}
```

Comment: ``role.toString()`` returns the role mention, the long numerical string that represents it.  I suspect you want ``role.name``.  Unfortunately due to language barrier, I'm not entirely sure that's the question you are asking.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for respond . I try to do command that when you mention someone It's show their important roles and it's always updating and Its update the message but not the roles. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by important roles? can you provide an example please

Comment: I mean specific roles